# Setting up MinGW with Eclipse Galileo on Windows

Tags: eclipse, gcc, mingw

Couldn't get it working on Windows 7 64 bits.

Comment: An answer without a question is useless (see: 42). You have the ability to write both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, here's how I got it working:

1) Install the makefile, c and c++ compilers during the mingw installation. Must be installed on C:\mingw
2) Go to C:\mingw\bin, copy the "mingw-make.exe" file and rename the copy to make.exe
3) Add "C:\mingw\bin" to the the PATH environment variable
4) Download the gdb.exe debugger and put it in the C:\mingw\bin folder
5) Install the CDT plugin to Eclipse, if it isn't already installed
6) In Eclipse, go to Window > Preferences. Now pick C/C++ > New CDT Project Wizards > Makefile project > mark PE Windows Parser
7) Still in the Window > Preferences menu, go C/C++ > Debug > Debugger Types and mark gdb Debugger
8) Confirm

Answer (score 2):

Here's another good tutorial for installing MinGW on Eclipse: http://chrismwright.wordpress.com/2012/10/13/installing-eclipse-for-cc-and-mingw/

Could be better with some pictures throughout the steps, but still a pretty comprehensive guide.