# Really difficult error arose in eclipse for C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, compilation

I just downloaded eclipse c/c++ IDE developer and made a C++ project. but then under problems tab, this comes up and I cannot proceed to do anything else from there.

```
sh-c "autoreconf-i"
```

Alright, I downloaded the MinGW. While installing, I clicked download original repository catalogues, accepted the agreement, and when it asked me to choose which optional components of MinGW to install, I clicked c++ compiler, at the bottom though there are like msys basic system and mingw developer toolkit, which I did not click. After I installed it, I went to computer properties then environment variables and then added `;C:\MinGW\bin` to Path. I then searched for cmd and typed in gcc. It outputted, `"gcc : fatal error : no input files"` and below that is `"compilation terminated."` . I clicked eclipse and clicked C++ project. But still there was no MinGW GCC under Toolchains. All I saw was GNU autotools Toolchain.

Comment: which OS ? are you sure that eclipse actually use the compiler you just installed ? have you installed more than one version of eclipse / MinGW ?

Comment: maybe this post will be solve your issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035558/setting-up-mingw-with-eclipse-galileo-on-windows. Hope this helps

Comment: I am using windows 7, 64 bit. that post is from 2 years and since then the installer has been updated and it now gives different options. I just downloaded the IDE C/C++ eclipse and MinGW. but when I create a new project, under toolchains, MinGW is not available and all I can see it GNU autotools Toolchain.

Comment: did you installed eclipse in 32-bits or 64 ? unless you can get every depencies in 64-bits, its somehow more safe in 32-bits if you want to use plugins and custom stuff; what's the name of your eclipse version ?