# Debug global variables in C with Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, global

inside a.h I defined a struct and used extern Struct *struct to use an instance of this struct in other .c files and my main.c file.

Following [this guide](http://eclipse.dzone.com/articles/debugging-global-variables) 
I click on the same icon but all I get is an empty window, where no variables are listed.

How do I fix this?

a.h defines Queue:

```
typedef struct Queue
{
    int size;
    q_elem *root;
} Queue;
```

and

```
extern Queue **queue;
```

a.c defines various functions queue-typical functions.

In b.c I define

```
Queue **queue;
```

as variable and work on it with several functions.
I work on the same **queue in my main.c file.

I use Eclipse 3.3.2 for Windows.

Comment: Show your code.  It will be easier to analyze.  Mention the environment you are working in.

Comment: Done. I can work on the queue just fine but it won't show up in my debug variables.

Comment: Apologies Putz, I am in the middle of a project requiring most all of my time.  In the event you have not solved your problem, and indeed are even still interested,  see the answer ***[HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2036076/645128)***.  It may have some of the steps you need. (assuming minGW is your compiler)

Comment: Another thought:  Instead of creating a copy of your struct as a pointer to pointer _**_, create it as both a struct and a pointer to struct.  To much to put here, see my proposed idea below.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with potentially two sources of error. 1 being type of declaration you are using, and 2 being the debugging environment you are using.

***Addressing 2 first***:  In my environment, (a National Instruments compiler/debugger) when resources get tight, the debugger begins to do flaky things, like display an array of structs incorrectly as a single struct, etc.  I saw this just yesterday after several hours of using my debugger.  The solution is to shut down and restart the environment to reset and clear all debugger memory.  All debuggers I have used are subject to this type of behavior.

***Addressing 1***:  First, the way you have your struct defined is not compilable.  i.e., the line:

```
q_elem *root;
```

Needs to be:

```
struct q_elem *root;
```

That alone may fix your problem. But you might also try to create the instance of your struct a little differently.  I have not seen how you are using it, but I assume you want to create an array of structs with extern linking (perhaps for the purpose of having project scope).  If this is the case, try this:

```
//In header file:

typedef struct QUEUE
{
    int size;
    struct QUEUE *root;
}QUEUE;

extern QUEUE queue[10], *pQueue;
```

***Then:***

```
//In .c file:

QUEUE queue[10], *pQueue;

int main(void)
{

    pQueue = &queue[0];

    //...
```

You now have a pointer to an array of QUEUE with project scope.  Note that it does not allocate memory for access to the member `*root`, For some *pointers* (no pun intended) on how to do that, ***[Look Here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson15.html)***.